# Convert uint64 to byte array in python

Tags: python, binary, integer, byte

I want to convert a 64 bit integer to a byte array of length 16.

For example, I want to convert `687198803487` to `[31 150 61 0 160 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]`

In Go, I'm able to do this using

```
id := make([]byte, 16)
binary.LittleEndian.PutUint64(id, uint64(687198803487))
```

How can I replicate this in Python 2?

Comment: Have a look at the [struct](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters) module. Format `d` deals with type `double`.

Comment: `struct.unpack('8B', struct.pack('>Q', x))[::-1]`

Comment: This is not a duplicate as the other question does not start from a uint64 or something similar

Answer (score 1):

Use `struct.pack` with `'<Q'` to do this. Here `<` indicates little-Endian, and `Q` means we want to pack an unsigned long long (8 bytes). If you want to convert it to 16 bytes, however, you have to fill zeros on your own (your input is only 64 bits after all).

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('<Q', 687198803487)
b'\x1f\x96=\x00\xa0\x00\x00\x00'
>>> list(map(int, struct.pack('<Q', 687198803487)))
[31, 150, 61, 0, 160, 0, 0, 0]
>>>
```

Comment: Please flag these questions as duplicates  instead of answering them.